# Scroll of edittext

Tags: android

I have one Edittext in my app that there is problems with its scroll, such as its slow and it not like scrollview.
I override its ontouch like this but there is some problems new.
Any one can help me ?!
there is any way for edittext to scroll like scroll view or webview ?!

```
historytv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case 0:
                    oldx=(int) event.getX();
                    oldy=(int) event.getY();
                    tevent = event.getEventTime();
                    return false;
                case 2:
                    tevent = (event.getEventTime() - tevent ) / 20 + 1;
                    final int x = (int) event.getX();
                    final int y = (int) event.getY();
                    final int   xx = oldx - x;
                    final int   yy = oldy - y;
                    if(yy< 4 && yy >-4)
                    {
                        oldx =x;
                        oldy=y;
                        tevent = event.getEventTime();
                        return false;
                    }
                X=xx;
                Y=yy;
                if(Math.abs(yy) <= Math.abs(xx) )
                {
                    historytv.scrollBy(2*xx,0);
                }
                else
                {
                    historytv.scrollBy(0,(int)(yy*tevent));

                }
                oldx =x;
                oldy=y;
                tevent = event.getEventTime();
                    return false;
                case 1:
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Instead of `TouchListener`, give a try with `historytv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);`  and `historytv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

Comment: First i try that but, so slow ...

Comment: edittext scroll is slow and not like scrollview